# Laravel - I can't return as validation error messages in the form (Using ClassRequest in ClassController)

Tags: php, laravel

I created the `HunterRequest.php` file to store the error messages from validations and make the methods in my `HunterController.php` file not need to load these validation messages, making that take up fewer lines of code and have a cleaner appearance. However, I am not able to return these messages in the form in my validation test because of an error.

[image: Error Message]

- `HunterRequest.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class HunterRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return 
        [
            'name_hunter' => 'required|max:50',
            'year_hunter' => 'required|numeric',
            'height_hunter' => 'required|numeric',
            'weight_hunter' => 'required|numeric',
            'type_hunter' => 'required|max:30',
            'type_nen' => 'required|max:30',
            'type_blood' => 'required|max:3',
        ];
    }
    // Customizing messages rules
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'name_hunter.required' => 'Hunter name can't be empty.',
            'name.max' => 'Hunter name must be a maximum of 30 characters.',
            'year_hunter.required' => 'Hunter year can't be empty.',
            'year_hunter.numeric' => 'Hunter age must be a whole number.',
            'height_hunter.required' => 'Hunter weight can't be empty.',
            'height_hunter.numeric' => 'Hunter weight must be a decimal number.',
            'weight_hunter.required' => 'Hunter weight can't be empty.',
            'weight_hunter.numeric' => 'Hunter weight must be a decimal number.',
            'type_hunter.required' => 'It is necessary to define the type of Hunter.',
            'type_hunter.max' => 'Hunter type must be a maximum of 30 characters.',
            'type_nen.required' => 'It is necessary to define the type Nen.',
            'type_nen.max' => 'Nen type must be a maximum of 30 characters.',
            'type_blood.required' => 'It is necessary to define the type blood.',
            'type_blood.max' => 'Blood type must be a maximum of 3 characters.',
        ];
    }
}
```

- `HunterController.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Requests\HunterRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\HunterModel;

class HunterController extends Controller {

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validacoes = $request->validate();
        HunterModel::create($validacoes);
        return redirect()->to('/');   
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $validacoes = $request->validate();
        HunterModel::where('id',$id)->update($validacoes);
        return redirect()->to('/');        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually make use of your custom request. So change your parameter type hint(s) from `Request` to `HunterRequest`.

```
public function store(HunterRequest $request)
{
    $validacoes = $request->validated();
    HunterModel::create($validacoes);
    return redirect()->to('/');   
}

public function update(HunterRequest $request, $id)
{
    $validacoes = $request->validated();
    HunterModel::where('id',$id)->update($validacoes);
    return redirect()->to('/'); 
}
```

Comment: ```Undefined type 'App\Http\Controllers\HunterRequest'.intelephense(1009)```

Comment: @DevoloperBebop You'll need to add a `use` statement.

Comment: ```use App\Http\Requests\HunterRequest;```

Comment: @DevoloperBebop Yes, have you added that to your `HunterController`?

Comment: It worked, but creating/updating the registry returns ```Too little arguments to function App\Http\Requests\HunterRequest::Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\{closure}(), 0 passed in C:\l9xl9\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Macroable\Traits\Macroable.php on line 124 and exactly 1 expected```.

Comment: @DevoloperBebop I have updated my answer, replacing `$request->validate()` with `$request->validated();`.